# How to do this proof without proof by contradiction?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am tired of only beeing able to proove things doing contradiction.

Please look at this exercise:

> Suppose that f is a nonnegative extended real-valued
>   $\mathcal{A}$-measurable function on $\Omega$ and that
>   $\int_{\Omega}f\,d\mu\ <\infty$. Prove that f is finite $\mu$-a.e.

By assuming that it is not finite a.e., we can look at simple functions at the set where f is ininity, and show that then the integral must be infinity.

But, is there a way of doing this without a contradiction proof? Is there a way to get this with a direct proof?

Comment: What you’ve described is not a proof by contradiction: it’s simply a proof of the contrapositive, which is logically equivalent to the original statement.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you, I guess you are correct, but I think it is also a proof by contradiction, because we get both that the integral must be infinity, and it is also less than infinity, by what is given in the exercise, so hence it is a contradiction. I think i read that all contrapositive proofs, are kind of contradition proofs by what I described above. So what I am looking for is a direct proof of the statement given in the problem(no contrapositive, or contradiction proof).

Comment: All proofs of the contrapositive can be phrased as proofs by contradiction; it’s just unnecessary. (And there are proofs by contradiction that cannot be turned into direct proofs of the contrapositive.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends a lot on what you mean by "contradiction". As Brian mentioned, using the contrapositive is a very natural and powerful idea; it is almost impossible to avoid it in cases where definitions are stated in terms of negation (in this case, either "finite" is defined as "not infinite" or "infinite" is defined as "not finite").

In any case, if $\int f<\infty$, let $r=\int f$, and let $E=\{t:\ f(t)=\infty\}$ and $E_n=\{t: f(t)>n\}$. Then
$$
\mu(E)\leq \mu(E_n)=\int_{E_n}1=\frac1n\,\int_{E_n}n\leq\frac1n\,\int_{E_n}f\leq\frac rn.
$$
As this holds for all $n$, $\mu(E)=0$.

Comment: Thank you, that was a cool proof!

Comment: My pleasure. This is a very well-known trick, that one usually learns with the Chebyshev Inequality.